# How can I test method from component that has been called from child component with React Testing Library and Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a Parent component which has a method that has been called from Child component. An example:

Parent.js

```js
export default function Parent() {

  const methodToTest = () => {
    //method code
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Child onChange={methodToTest} />
    </div>
  )
  
}
```

Child.js

```js
export default function Child({ onChange }) {

  const handleChange = () => {
    onChange()
  }

  //InaccesibleElement is a component from a library that not render the element in test instance.
  return (
    <div>
      ....
      <InaccesibleElement onClick={() => handleChange()} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I would thinking to mock Child and inject into Parent component but doesn't work or I don't know how to do it correctly. My test example:

Parent.test.js

```js
function ChildMock({ onChange }) {

    const handleChange = () => {
        onChange("mockedValue");
    }

    return(
        <button onClick={() => handleChange()}>click me</button>
    )
}

jest.mock('../components/Child', () => {
        return { Child: ChildMock}
    })
    
test("test parent method", () => {
  const component = render(<Parent />);
  
  const button = component.getByText("click me");
  
  //rest of the test...
})
```

jest.mock() throws an exception:
"Reference error: The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.
Invalid variable access: BarGraphContainerMock
Allowed objects: Array, ArrayBuffer, Atomics, BigInt, BigInt64Array, BigUint64Array, Boolean, Buffer, DataView, Date, ....
Note: This is a precaution to guard against uninitialized mock variables. If it is ensured that the mock is required lazily, variable names prefixed with `mock` (case insensitive) are permitted."

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you rename ChildMock to MockChild?

Comment: Ok now it's building, but if I use component.getByText("click me") can't find the element button--

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Parent from './Parent';
import Child from './Child';

describe('Parent', () => {
  it('should call methodToTest when Child component onChange is called', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Parent />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    const methodToTestSpy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'methodToTest');

    const child = wrapper.find(Child);
    child.props().onChange();

    expect(methodToTestSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).